# Not able to open Spring MVC .jsp in JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, spring, jqgrid

I have developed a Spring MVC application along with JQGrid. Relevant part of my .js file is as below wherein I am opening a JQuery Dialog box, when user clicks the 'select' custom button from the ADD/Edit dialog of the JQGrid. Dialog box gets opened, but not the .jsp file whose path is given in the load method of the JQuery Dialog.

My .js file is as below:

```
          function JQDialog(title, contentUrl, params) {
                var dialog1 = $("<div>").dialog(
                {
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    title: title,
                    close: function (e, ui) { (dialog1).remove(); },
                    buttons: { "Ok": function () { (dialog1).dialog("close"); } }
                });

                dialog1.load(contentUrl, function () {
                     dialog1.dialog('open');
                });


            }


 $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:false}, 
         { 
           recreateForm: true, dataheight: 375, width: 400, height: 450,
           beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#trv_ccode',form).hide();

           $('<a href="#">Select<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span></a>')
            .click(function(rowid, iRow, iCol, cellValue, e) {
                    JQDialog('Test Dialog',"../acctmstmgmt/opendlg",'');
```

However, when I open window with following code my .jsp file gets opened.

```
window.open("../acctmstmgmt/opendlg", 'Dialog', 'width=700,height=300', top=500, left=500 );
```

What could be the reason? any solution?

Comment: Is the path correct in the JQDialog - JQDialog('Test Dialog',"../acctmstmgmt/opendlg",'');

Comment: @cDima Yes, Path is correct since window.open function opens the .jsp correctly.

Comment: You have a `..` in the open window and not in the JQDialog.

Comment: @cDima, that's right, but I have checked it with .. and without it both, but couldn't succeed.

Comment: To clarify further, I have changed the path same as window.open

Comment: Pl. help me resolving the issue